# NullPointerException emergs when I try to extract data from a hbase table using newAPIHadoopRDD

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.allTableRegions(MetaScanner.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HRegionLocator.getAllRegionLocations(HRegionLocator.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSizeCalculator.init(RegionSizeCalculator.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSizeCalculator.<init>(RegionSizeCalculator.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1953)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:933)
    at com.dnvgl.eta.HbaseToCsv$.main(HbaseToCsv.scala:69)
    at com.dnvgl.eta.HbaseToCsv.main(HbaseToCsv.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.getMetaReplicaNodes(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    ... 40 more
```

can any one give some advices? thank you very much.

Comment: val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()

conf.setInt("timeout", 120000)   conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","xx, yy ,zz")
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)

    val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its harder to answer with only the stacktrace been posted. Please revise the question with the source code that you use.

I'm doubting that the HBase configuration object that you pass to the `newAPIHadoopRDD` method is not configured properly. [Refer to this URL](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/72479/hbase-using-java-api-to-put-data-into-table-gives.html) to understand better. Make sure the config object captures the hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort, hbase.zookeeper.quorum and zookeeper.znode.parent parameters

Comment: thank you very much. the issue is resolved after i add zookeeper.znode.parent